# OBIEE 10G: Round off issue

Tags: oracle, obiee

In my project we are facing  OBIEE round off issue as explained below.
Please suggest is there a way to get this solution in OBIEE or this is not possible through tool. We tried lot of ways nothing worked out.

We have forecast/budget data as thousands in database table .
We have a requirement to show the data in nearest million . The report has been 
developed in pivot view with couple of prompts .

**The business requirement is to show the data in nearest million on the report and 
when downloaded to excel , it should  show data in million but the whole number 
needs to be in background so they can manipulate with that .  (means in excel on select it should show real numbe with Decimal )**

Following are the technical details which is used in OBIEE  report :

formula = forcast/1000
data format --> Override Default Data Format -->decimal places -->0
When we export this report to excel, it exported the data in millions but  if they 
want to see the whole number for manipulation , the cant do that .
Following are in example :
database data in thousands : say 5,977.71
OBIEE report should show value in Million : 6 
Once downloaded to excel it should show data in million : 6 
With the above scenario ,  business user can not manupulate thew data further because whole data is not available in exported excel  background.

The exported excel needs to have  5,977.71 in the background so that they can manipulate (like they can add or subtract data  and change rounding to million ).

Thanks,
Shrikant

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you can do that. What you can try is, hide the column in the report and then download it. You might get both the columns (rounded and whole number) in the XLS file.